# Histogram in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4, histogram

I would like to plot a 1D histogram (bar chart) on my Python application using PyQt4. Anyone have a code example on how to do this or can refer me to an example?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Two possible solutions would be:

- Embedding a [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) plot in PyQt ([example](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html))
- Using [PyQwt](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/home.html) extensions ([examples](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/gui-examples.html))